# Как изменить значение переменной в С++ с помощью значения этой переменной в файле?

Tags: c++

Как изменить значение переменной в С++ с помощью значения этой переменной в файле?

Comment: Смотря какой переменной и смотря из какого файла. Слишком общий вопрос. Уточните.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрим код.

```
#include < iostream>
#include < fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int val;

    // записываем
    ofstream file1("value.txt");
    file1 << 42;
    file1.close();
    //закрываем

    //открываем и читаем
    ifstream file2("value.txt");
    file2 >> val;
    file2.close();
    // закрываем и печатаем значение

    cout << val << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Где мой плюс?

Comment: "Смотрим код" и видим полное отсутствие проверок правильности данных.

Comment: Я написал самый простой пример, что бы показать основной принцип.

Comment: @embarcadero, считайте мой комментарий адресованным @exmp2012, на что надо обратить внимание, после того, как он узнал про данный путь изменения значения переменной.